How to save emails that only remain on a disconnected device and were deleted in the cloud?
I use gmail as my main email and have my iPhone set to use gmail. A while ago I deleted a collection of emails and wished I hadn't from gmail itself.
The other day I realised that they are still in my Mail app on my iPhone - I hadn't remembered Mail was also storing gmail emails.
However, they are - I think - only on the iPhone because I changed my gmail password. I am fairly sure as soon as I supply the new password to Mail, it will sync and they will be lost?
So I have these emails in my Mail->Sent folder but nowhere else. How can I get them out, in whatever form (email, text, etc?)

How many mails are we talking about here?

I can't find anything that backs up email on the iPhone. However if you have another email account somewhere you could, perhaps, add THAT account to the iPhone and copy those messages to a folder in the other account and then sync that account to your Mac or PC. Just thinking out loud here but is sounds like it might work even though it is a PITA workaround....

@nohillside perhaps 20

Just forward them to yourself!

@nohillside that's rather the point, the mail client isn't logged in. As soon as it is, it will sync and they will disappear.

Stay disconnected, start Mail, forward each message to yourself, then connect.

@nohillside oh that's interesting. I think that is worthy of being an answer - you're right as soon as the new emails are composed they are 'safe'. Thanks

If you are going to use this approach, stay disconnected from Gmail, forward them to some other service.

Print them.  When Mail.app asks what printer, hit the share button and save them as PDF.  You did say "in whatever form".



the only issue here is having to do that for each individual email. But yes this is a valuable option thanks

As we are only looking at a handful of emails:
While still disconnected from any network,

open Mail
forward each mail to yourself.
connect to a network
wait for the forwards to be sent, and the original mails to be deleted by the sync

